# Are graduate programs included College Scorecard data?

Tags: collegescorecard

Are graduate programs included College Scorecard https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/ website data?

Answer (score 3):

At present, the tool is focused on undergraduates.  The Department of Education is considering options for expanding College Scorecard in the future.

Comment: that will definitely be helpful. There is not information available on graduate programs as of now