# Graduate students included in loan repayment and/or earnings data?

Tags: collegescorecard

Are graduate students included in loan repayment and/or earnings data?  The documentation does not specify.  If these data pertain to undergraduates only, how are undergraduate students identified?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are graduate programs included College Scorecard data?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6059/are-graduate-programs-included-college-scorecard-data)

Comment: can you add more context to your question. Which documentation are you referring to? Are you talking about a specific country? administrative area (state, province or region?)

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of Scorecard, student cohorts for loan repayment, earnings, and other outcome metrics are constructed with undergraduate students only.